# How to set Zoom in Camera of HTC Sensation?

Tags: android, camera, zooming

```
public void setZoomIn(){
    try{
        params = camera.getParameters();
        zoomValue +=5;
        params.setZoom(zoomValue);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        Log.d(TAG, "Is support Zoom " + params.isZoomSupported());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hi all, the code above successfully set zoom on Camera of Samsung, LG Phone. However, it crashes with HTC Sensation.
In HTC Sensation, the default camera application run zoom function wonderfully. I don't know why?
Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've a similar problem: HTC Sensation, Android 2.3.4:
isSmoothZoomSupported(): false, isZoomSupported(): true, getMaxZoom(): 0. RuntimeException on every setParameters() with setZoom() set, even with zoom level 0.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not be checking for the zoom support before you set it?

And in addition check the max zoom limit that the device supports by using 'getMaxZoom()'. This value should act as the upper limit for your set call.